# Jupyter notebook truncates last page when printing

Tags: printing, jupyter-notebook

Has anyone encountered the problem of trying to print an entire Jupyter Notebook where the last page was excluded?

I've tried downloading my .ipynb as a PDF but there's tons of stuff that get's truncated if my lines are too long horizontally. I can work around this with linebreaks but it's a bit annoying.

I've tried using Print Preview but doing so excludes the last page of content.

I've also tried converting my .ipynb file to HTML:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to html filename.ipynb
```

and then opening it in Google Chrome to print from there but experience the same problem as with a regular print preview.

Are there any suggestions out there?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind y'all, I found a solution. In case anyone is new to nbconvert, you can install it with anaconda as:

```
conda install nbconvert
```

Then after you're done with your Jupyter notebook and are ready to print, you can use your terminal to convert to a PDF:

```
Jupyter nbconvert --to pdf filename.ipynb
```

This will produce a PDF you can print normally! I hope this helps someone.